# How to SFTP through proxy if there is no netcat?

Tags: ssh, proxy, sftp

```
sftp -v -oProxyCommand="nc -v PROXY_IP_HERE PROXY_PORT_HERE %h %p" user@remote_sftp_server.com 22
```

How can I do this if I don't have netcat installed? I don't have permission to install it, even in my home directory. There is no tsocks/socksify either.

Comment: Do you just not have root, or are you actually prohibited from installing any software? If its just lack of root, you could install netcat in your home directory.

Comment: Prohibited from installing anything.